# Dynamic change the display of network status

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information for my ionic 1 APP.

It’s no problem to detect the network status. However, I got a problem is that when I changed the network from wifi to 4G. The status can’t be changed dynamic, it will still keep showing wifi in the view. May I know how to make the status change dynamic ?

Below is my code. Many thanks.

**controller.js**

```
.controller(‘NetworkCtrl', function($scope) {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
    $scope.networkstatus = states[networkState];
})
```

**Network.html**

```
 {{networkstatus}}
```